# "Something came up. The application has cancelled the request to choose a device"

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, connection-issues, android-10, oneplus-5t

I'm a tech savy person but this has me at my wits end.

I have two apps and two devices I want to connect to with my OnePlus 5T running Android 10, OxygenOS 10.0.1

- [Image Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ricohimaging.imagesync&hl=en_CA&gl=US), trying to connect to Pentax KS2
- [GoPro Quik](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gopro.smarty&hl=en_CA&gl=US), trying to connect to GoPro Hero Silver 7.

For Image Sync, this is what happens:

1. On my phone: turn on NFC
2. Turn on my Pentax camera.
3. Open the app on my phone, click on "cam images" to try to download the camera's pictures.
4. App wants me to connect through NFC or through wi-fi. I pick NFC and put the camera near the phone.
5. The connection seems to work, I see "connection successful" at the bottom of my phone. Then a popup lets me select my camera. I click "connect" and immediately after, another popup appears saying "Something came up. The application has cancelled the request to choose a device"
6. If I go the wi-fi route, the same thing happens.

For the GoPro, my phone is able to find my camera but when I try to download the images, it says "connecting" and nothing happens. Then another popup: "we had trouble connecting with your GoPro".

My phone has developer mode turned on. Is there a setting that i'm missing? It can't be that both apps are faulty, right? It has to be my phone.

I've tried various combinations of connections on my phone turned on/off: wi-fi, bluetooth, data. Nothing works.

Comment: If you've enabled developer mode have you looked at [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) [logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3707880/295004) to see if any related message appears when attempting the action.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I tried that but I didn't get a lot of useful information

Answer (score 2):

Well this is what worked.

For GoPro:

1. Phone: Clear all active apps and clear the app's cache.
2. Phone: "Forget" the camera on the app, and also forget the WiFi network.
3. Phone: Turn off data connection, leave only wi-fi and Bluetooth.
4. Turn on the camera, WiFi should be enabled automatically.
5. Phone: connect to the WiFi network normally, through the phone settings.
6. Phone: open app, connection should work.

For Image Sync:

1. Phone: Clear the apps' cache AND local data.
2. Phone: Forget the camera's WiFi network.
3. Phone: Turn off data connection, leave only wi-fi and Bluetooth.
4. Turn on the camera and enable its WiFi.
5. Phone: connect to the WiFi network normally, through the phone settings.
6. Phone: Open the app. It will ask you to accept terms and conditions and some permissions.